# makedepf90: program for automatic creation of Makefile-style dependency lists for Fortran source code

Tags: software-installation, makefile, fortran

I assumed it is only a couple of seconds installing this program, but it confuses me honestly.
this program is for the automatic creation of Makefile-style dependency lists for Fortran source code.

I follow the guide but "./configure [options]" step is not working,
the developer says something to somehow fix this error but I am not expert enough to know what "**tweaking**" means.
I tried to follow the lines 50-66 of this README as solution, but had no luck:
https://github.com/outpaddling/makedepf90/blob/master/readme

the program:
https://github.com/outpaddling/makedepf90

Any salvation guys ???

peace

Comment: Please try to be more specific than *"is not working"* - what happens exactly? Please include any error messages. What guide are you following? What steps did you perform prior to `./configure [options]` and what `[options]` did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy solution that one friend probably mentioned here but is not anymore,
I write instead of him/her:

It is a ubuntu universe package apparently:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/makedepf90

so in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install makedepf90
```

have fun.